# Add item to sidebar in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, navigation

I want to add "team explorer" and solution explorer" to the side bar. I have tried choosing "float", dock then dragging and dropping ( shows the little navigation boxes' everything. How do I add them ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an older post but if you are still looking for an answer or maybe someone else...

Grab the team explorer (or anything else you want to add) and drop it at the left side of VS. After this just select "Auto Hide" at the Window Position options.

[image: Add item to sidebar in Visual Studio]